# Count Subarrays Where Max Element Appears at Least K Times sliding window

Tags: python, algorithm, sliding-window

### Problem

**[Count Subarrays Where Max Element Appears at Least K Times](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-subarrays-where-max-element-appears-at-least-k-times/description/)**

You are given an integer array `nums` and a positive integer `k`. Return the number of subarrays where the maximum element of `nums` appears at least `k` times in that subarray.
A subarray is a contiguous sequence of elements within an array.

### Logic

- Go through the windows, if currently you have less than `k maxElement counts` keep widening the window
- If you have `more than equal to k maxElement counts`, increment `ans` and work on shortening/sliding the window

### Code

```
class Solution:

    def countSubarrays(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        i = j = 0
        count = 0
        ans = 0 
        N = len(nums)
        max_element = max(nums)
    
        while j < N:
            # keep increasing the window
            if count < k:
                count+= nums[j] == max_element
                j+=1
            # slide/decrease the window
            else:
                ans+=1
                if nums[i] == max_element:
                    count-=1
                i+=1
    
        return ans
```

### Issue

Possible issues could be

- I am failing to consider last subarray that could be shortened or atleast consider to be added in the `ans` variable.
- I am not sliding the window correctly because I could go right as well as left. Consider `nums = [1,3,2,3,3]` and K current subarray being `[3,2,3]` I already satisfied `count >= k` so instead of considering `[3,2,3,3]` I would work on shortening the subarray.
- I know that I can brute force a while loop (while count>=k increment i until this agreement gets broken) but I believe this still doesn't solve the problem. This could still happen in an if condition (if count >=k and freezing j until the agreement gets broken) so, any help is appreciated. I wish we can find a solution where if count >=k we dont increment j until we bring back count < k and continue increasing j later
- If you need a specific case, this code fails at `nums=[1,3,2,3,3] and k = 2 Output = 2 Expected Output = 6` The two subarrays being `[1, 3, 2, 3] and [3, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `else` clause, you just increment the result. But actually all sub-arrays starting at `i` with an end index `>= j` will satisfy the condition. So instead of `ans += 1` you have to do `ans += N - j`. Other than that your algorithm seems fine.

Comment: See my thought process was i go through window and if a window satisfies conditions, then i increment it. Similar to if i was counting a sum and i wanted to count how many k length subarrays had sum s. But every solution of sliding window i read, they count 'how many subarrays with this ending' instead of counting windows and seeing if they fit the criteria add 1 if they do, move to the next window if they dont

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, as also mentioned by @maraca, when you encounter a sub-array ending at `j`, you need to count all sub-arrays that start at the same `i` and end at `j`, `j+1`, ..., `N`. Secondly, your loop terminates the first time you process the final `3` in the array because `j == N`. This means the sub-arrays `[2, 3, 3]` and `[3, 3]` are not counted.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code that doesn't have those issues:

```py
def countSubarrays(self, nums: list[int], k: int) -> int:
    i = j = 0
    count = 0
    ans = 0 
    N = len(nums)
    max_element = max(nums)
    
    while i <= N - k:
        while count < k and j < N:
            count += nums[j] == max_element
            j += 1
        
        # have we found a valid subarray? if so, every array from j to N will also be one
        if count == k:
            ans += N - j + 1
        
        # increment i and reset count if required
        count -= nums[i] == max_element
        i += 1
    
    return ans
```